# create/retrieve multiple instances of inner class python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have a scenario where I have a class say ABC and few inner classes say P and T. I need to store multiple objects of the inner class (say P). I'll be needing them in code and want to have a quick insert/retrieval logic. How can this be achieved in python?

```
class ABC:

    def __init__(self):
        print('In ABC INIT!!') 

    class P:
        id = ''
        description = ''

    class T:
        id = ''
        description = ''
```

Comment: I can create multiple instances like   abc = ABC()
p = abc.P()
t = abc.T()
But how i should store these objects so that I can get quick retrieval for the attributes of the objects.